# Set time unit within which lubridate::floor_date operates

Tags: r, lubridate

lubridate's `floor_date` (and similarly `ceiling_date` and `round_date`) allows rounding down to multiples of time units (e.g `"7 days"`) but the break points are nested within another unspecified unit of time. Can this other unit of time (or similarly the break-points where the rounding occurs) be specified? How can one know which unit is being used?

For example, take the following sample of six contiguous days:

```
x <- as.Date("2019-05-27") + 0:5
```

and round each date down to nearest 7-day increment:

```
x_7d <- lubridate::floor_date(x, "7 days")
```

Note that these six contiguous dates are assigned to three separate 7-day intervals, one of which is only three-days long (05-29 to 05-31).

```
#> data.frame(x, x_7d)
#           x       x_7d
#1 2019-05-27 2019-05-22
#2 2019-05-28 2019-05-22
#3 2019-05-29 2019-05-29
#4 2019-05-30 2019-05-29
#5 2019-05-31 2019-05-29
#6 2019-06-01 2019-06-01
```

It seems the "7 days" intervals are predefined and occur within each month, but can this be modified? Can we round to 7-day intervals within each year or within a user-defined period (e.g., starting on 2019-05-27)?

Comment: It looks as if rounding to `7 days` just takes the day element of the date, and rounds it down to the previous multiple of 7, plus 1 (so `1:7`, `8:14`, etc are the separate periods).  To round in other ways it might make more sense to use `week` as the rounding unit, rather than `7 days`, - you can use a `week_start` parameter, and perhaps add or subtract days if you want something non-standard.

Comment: @AndrewGustar "just takes the day element of the date" - Ah, this makes sense and helps me understand what it's doing. For 7 days, I agree "week" makes sense. In this case I am looking for a general solution for any multiple of any unit, not specifically 7 days (choice was arbitrary).

Comment: In that case, you might find `yday` and `qday` useful in the lubridate package.